# Looking for guidance: Error working with functions in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working with functions right now and I'm currently getting the following error in line 3 (my first bracket):

"expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token"

I'm not sure what this means, and I couldn't find relavant information on the net. Would someone be able to explain this error?

I've included my whole function prototype just in case, sorry if it's overkill.

Thanks for your help

```
void admission(double gpa, int score);

{
    if (gpa < 0.0||gpa > 4.0);
    {
        cout << "GPA must be between 0.0 and 4.0. Enter your GPA: ";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (score < 0 || score > 100);
    {
        cout << "Test Score must be between 0 and 100. Enter the score: ";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (gpa >= 3.6 && score >= 60);
    {
    cout << "The admission result is: Accepted!";
    }
    else if (gpa >= 3.0 && score >= 70);
    {
    cout << "The admission result is: Accepted!";
    }
    else if (gpa >= 2.6 && score >= 80);
    {
    cout << "The admission result is: Accepted!";
    }
    else if (gpa >= 2.0 && score >= 90);
    {
    cout << "The admission result is: Accepted!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "The admission result is: Rejected.";
    }

}
```

I'm expecting this function to gather user inputs (gpa, score) between 0-4.0 and 0-100, respectively. The function will then output whether or not the student is admitted based on the given inputs.

Running the program with this function as it is results in the error stated above.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon at the end of line 1.

Comment: All lines with if also need the semicolon removed.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, a semi-colon is used only to end statements. Whenever you need to create a block of statements (indicated by `{`), you don't use a semicolon.

For example, your function

```
void admission(double gpa, int score);

{
    ....              //This is a block
}
```

Should be:

```
void admission(double gpa, int score)

{
    ....
}
```

Note the absence of the `;`.

This not only goes for functions, but your `if-else` statements as well.

Answer (score 1):

When the function description is followed by a semicolon it makes it a function declaration, you are defining a function. Remove the semicolon from the first line.

You have also put unwanted semicolons after each if statement, these also need removing if your code is to function as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon in line 1. Credits: @tillaert from the comments